# When I click on a row, it should go to another list page

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a bunch of campaigns like this

[image]

Whenever I click on a row, I want to see the list of activities for that campaign, like this in react-admin

[image]

I tried to use rowClick option but it didnt appear like it can do that. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a function to the rowClick function which has this signature:
`(id, basePath, record) => string`.

Make it return the path to your list: `/my-resource`.

You may even include filters, sort and pagination parameters:
`/my-resource?filter={}&sort=date&order=DESC&page=1&perPage=10`.